# Getting Mysql $Row and query

Tags: php, mysql

i have made this code to get the top 5 songs views:

```
$mysqli_query ="SELECT page, count( * ) AS 'Cnt'
FROM pageview
GROUP BY page
ORDER BY `Cnt` DESC
LIMIT 5 ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysqli_query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<br>Top 5 Song views:<br>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo " <a href=/songs.php?id=".$row["id"]." target=\"_blank\">" .$row["page"]."</a><br />";     


    }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

//fim 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And it is working, but the $row["id"] is missing, in my mind i have to make another query, my question is can i join this in the existing query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you should do this

```
$mysqli_query ="SELECT id,page, count( * ) AS 'Cnt'
                FROM pageview
               GROUP BY page
               ORDER BY `Cnt` DESC
               LIMIT 5 ";
```

Comment: Yes thats it, i forget about that, what a basic question! thank you.